# Why this (Request) module is not working in my project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am still very new to electron but I have a problem that I can not solve. The request is not going out to any website. I am using a windows 10 (x64) machine to make my project.

I wanted to store the body(html) into an array that will be called back in the index.html file. The call back works fine. It has been tested.

Here is the code for the .js file

```
 function data( callback){
   var content = [];
   var request = require('request');

   request('https://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
         if(error){
              content.push('Error:', error);
         }
         if(response.statusCode !== 200){
              content.push('Invalid Status Code Returned:', response.statusCode);
         }
              content.push(body);
              callback(content);
    });


 } 
module.exports = data;
```

In the html file I call data

```
var data require('./data.js')

data function(content){
   alert(content);
}
```

If I am missing something please give me some advise on it.

Comment: Your second block of code make no sense and is not legal Javasscript.  Also when you say "not working", you need to describe both the desired behavior and the observed behavior so we know what you expect the code to do and you can tell us what the current and undesired behavior is.  Otherwise this question is off-topic and unclear and will be closed.

Comment: my goal is to get google html into an array then call it in the index.html file. I made a mistake with "data =".... If there is something else I am missing please state. I am still new

Answer (score 0):

Your second block of content, assuming its javascript should be:

```js
var data = require("./data.js");

data(function(content){
 alert(content);
});
```

When you declare a variable, you assign a value to it using the "=" sign.

Function invocation is done by typing the name of the function and ending it with "()". Inside "()" you may pass function parameters, which in your case is a callback.

Comment: I made a mistake with the "="...... the function is called with  a callback parameter. the only thing I am trying to accomplish is getting google html in an array. If I am missing something please explain......

Comment: As @jfriend00 said, the second code snipet you provided is not valid javascript. In your code you are not calling data and not passing a callback. Please make sure you change your code to exactly how is indicated in the answer above.

Comment: The code is JavaScript. I called it in the index.html file. the first block of code is in a "data.js" file. if There is something I'm doing incorrectly please state. thanks